# Change module pattern to allow numbers at start of word

Tags: 8

I am using the Hashtag module and I would like it to allow an hashtag word to start with a number. Currently, the module doesn't allow an hashtag word to start with a number.

The code it uses is the following.

```
$pattern = "/[\s>]+?#([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*[^<\s[:punct:]])/iu";
```

I would like it to allow alpha-number or number-aplha.

Comment: Is this a feature request? Then please open a feature request in the module's issue queue. And consider that the module does this for a reason. Because variables must not start with numbers and doing so may cause difficulties in other places, Twig maybe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I will follow it up in the module issue queue. I was just hoping that there was a quick way to modify/remove the validation.